# Cannot solve method makeText

Tags: java, android

I'm new to developing and i bought a book, Big Nerd Ranch Guide to Android Programming. I finished chapter 2 and everything worked fine on this app it showed me how to make. Now im trying to do the challenges at the end and it wont work. Its giving me an error for something i didnt change at all, and it worked yesterday. The challenge wanted me to add a Previous button to the mix.

"Cannot solve method 'makeText(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener, int, int)'

The error is at the very bottom where im trying to create a Toast.

```
package com.example.lthol.geoquiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private Button mPrevButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;

    private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[] {
            new Question(R.string.question_australia, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
    };

    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

        mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(true);
            }
        });

        mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(false);
            }
        });

        mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();

        mPrevButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
        mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                        updateQuestion();

            }
        });

        updateQuestion();
    }

    private void updateQuestion() {
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }

    private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
        boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();

        int messageResId = 0;

        if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
            messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
        } else {
            messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code and your complaint do not line up. Make sure that the code in your question is the same code that is giving you the error. You will not get your cited error from this code. You *would* get that error if your `Toast.makeText()` code was inside one of your `OnClickListener` `onClick()` methods.

Comment: at the very bottom of the provided code, in android studio, is underlined and says "cannot solve method makeText.."

Comment: You seem to be missing some closing braces in your `onClickc()` methods, which may be contributing to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The mPrevButton onClick listener is actually contained in the mNextButton implementation. You need to close the bracket so that they are separate.